# convert Datatable to csv file in R

Tags: r, datatable, rdata, rexcel, shiny-reactivity

I uploaded an excel file into shiny R using following code:

Server.r

```
#reative function to read a table
MDPData<-reactive({
  file1<-input$MDPhistorical
  if(is.null(file1)){return()}
  z<-as.data.frame(read.xlsx(file1$datapath,sheetName = 'Probability Matrix'))      
})

#file info  
output$MDPDataTable<-DT::renderDataTable({
  if(is.null(MDPData())){return()}
  MDPData()
  DT::datatable(MDPData(),extensions = 'Responsive', options = list(pageLength=3), class = 'cell-border stripe', selection = "single")
})
```

relevant codes for ui.r:

```
fluidRow(
  box(
    title = "Historical Data of different conditions", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
    collapsible = TRUE,
    DT::dataTableOutput("MDPDataTable")
   )
)
```

Then I want to save MDPDataTable as a  csv file. 
I tried to use write.csv :

```
write.xlsx(MDPDataTable,'www/probabilitymatrix.csv')
```

and the Error is as follows:

```
Warning: Error in is.data.frame: object 'MDPDataTable' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    42: is.data.frame
    41: write.xlsx
    40: server [C:\Users\foad\Desktop\DSS Journal\NSS Protorype\Nss-28-2-17/server.R#902]
     1: shiny::runApp
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'MDPDataTable' not found
```

Comment: You don't want to write the HTML table to a CSV file, the data is stored in `MDPData()`. Use `write.xlsx(MDPData(),'www/probabilitymatrix.csv')` although it's unclear exactly where you tried to run that. It needs to be somewhere that reactive object is available.

Comment: Thanks but when I wrote MDPData , it gives me another error: Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working and Error appears because as MrFlick said, Your `write.xlsx(...)` function must be in reactive object. I guess You are using `ShinyApp` and to download `data` you have a `downloadButton`, then the code would look like that:

ui.R:

`downloadButton('download',label='Download data')`

server.R:

`output$download <- downloadHandler(
 "probabilitymatrix.csv", content = function(file) {
 write.xlsx(MDPData(),'www/probabilitymatrix.csv')})`